# Choosing an eloquent object by ID in Blade/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have hundreds of objects, let's call them boxes, in a Database.

This would be the structure.

```
id
user_id
size_id
color_id
shape_id
```

Now I got a "size" entry for the database with these entries:

```
id = 1
name = small
id = 2
name = big
```

Same with the rest, such as color:

```
id = 1
name = red
id = 2
name = blue
id = 3
name = green
id = 4
name = yellow
```

And same with shape. You know the drill.

I want to make a table with Blade. This would be the controller:

```
$boxes = boxes::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get();
$sizes = size::all();
$colors = colors::all();
$shapes = shapes::all();
return view()... etc etc
```

Now in the HTML/Blade:

```
@foreach($boxes as $box)
<td>{{$box->name}}</td>
<td>{{$sizes->...}}</td>
<td>{{$shape->...}}</td>
<td>{{$color->...}}</td>
...
```

I want to choose the name of size/shape/color based on the ID given in box.

How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method to load all reated data:

```
boxes::with('size', 'color', 'shape')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();
```

Then in the view:

```
@foreach($boxes as $box)
    <td>{{ $box->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $box->size->... }}</td>
    <td>{{ $box->shape->... }}</td>
    <td>{{ $box->color->... }}</td>
```

To make this work you also need to define [`belongsTo()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationship for each model in the `Box` class:

```
public function size()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Size::class);
}

public function shape()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Shapes::class);
}

public function color()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Colors::class);
}
```